# Android app is published successfully but when hit the URL it's not visible message "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: android, deployment, google-play, publish, mobile-application

[release status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cksOy.png)
[play store given url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwSV8.png)

I have published my app on google play, the app is successfully rolled out and it gives active status but when go to the link on the play store the page return we can't find this URL. I have also attached the screenshots

Comment: It takes time for a new app to propagate to all the google play servers around the world. Just wait. Make sure you published it in the production track.

Comment: Same here. Published since 2 days and still no working url.